# Style: Selection color on editable QComboBox

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, styling

selection-color and selection-background-color doesn't work on an editable QComboBox.

There is a way to make it work?

I'm using the following stylesheet, but it doesn't work when QComboBox is editable.

`QComboBox {
    selection-color: black;
    selection-background-color:#8FBC8F;
    color: black;
}`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use the pseudo-state "editable" like this:

```
QComboBox:editable {
    selection-color: black;
    selection-background-color:#8FBC8F;
    color: black;
}
```